# Is there a way to clear the last line of stdin and later restore it?

Tags: go, io, stdout, stdin

I'm trying to create a messaging client with a terminal interface. The problem I'm having is I want to print messages to stdout while the user might be typing into stdin. When I do this the user input typed into stdin get disrupted by the message. Is there any way to clear the last line of stdin, then print to stdout and then restore the last line of stdin so the user can finish their message?

Currently I read from stdin with `bufio.Reader.ReadString('\n')`
and I print to stdout with the normal `fmt.Println` and `fmt.Printf` functions

An example of the current situation:

```
# user is typing message
Hey Stan ho
# message from other user comes in
# it is: "Hey Bart"
# last line in terminal is now:
Hey Stan hoHey bart
```

What I want is to clear the "Hey Stan ho" then print the incoming message and then put the "Hey Stan ho" back

Comment: you may need advanced terminal libraries such as termbox-go. see all available library list at https://github.com/avelino/awesome-go#advanced-console-uis

Comment: I think it is conceptually wrong to log to the same underlying device (the terminal) you use to interact with the user. And if you absolutely need to do so, it would simply be best practice to interact with the user _first_ and then start to log.